# How to fix coverity warning PW.SWITCH_SELECTOR_EXPR_IS_CONSTANT

Tags: c++, coverity

My c++ code like this

```
    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& getAvailabilityStatus(std::ostream& os,
            const boost::optional<T::EAvailabilityStatus>& availabilityStatus)
    {
        switch (*availabilityStatus)
        {
            case T::EAvailabilityStatus_in__Space__test:
                return os << "availabilityStatus: InTest";
            case T::EAvailabilityStatus_failed:
                return os << "availabilityStatus: Failed";
        }
        return os;
    }
```

and got coverity warning like this:

CID 1923911 (#2 of 2): Parse warning (PW.SWITCH_SELECTOR_EXPR_IS_CONSTANT)

1. switch_selector_expr_is_constant: selector expression is constant

I don't know what this warning means and how to get rid of this warning by changing code(not to disable coverity)

Comment: Did you ever find more information about this Coverity warning, what the actual problem is with using a `const` variable is the `switch` expression, and what the "correct" way to do this is? I'm encountering the same problem, but I'm not finding any helpful results.

Comment: so far no proper solutions are found. I even remove the "const" from the parameter, the same warning still be reported. BUT i found some interesting code with Macro, which dont have such issue:
#define STATE_PRINTER(mo) \
    std::ostream& operator<<( \
        std::ostream& os, \
        const boost::optional<mo::State>& uState) \
    { \
        if (uState) \
        { \
            switch (*uState) \
            { \
                case mo::EUsageState_Idle: \
                    return os << "usageState: Idle"; \
            } \
        } \
        return os; \
    }

Comment: My coworker surmises that it's a faulty inspection that doesn't differentiate between global constants (which can never change, are inlined by the compiler, and would result in a useless switch) and local constants (which can change on each execution of the containing block). I'm going to file a bug against Coverity.